# Element found on bottum of web page as well

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, bots

Basically I feel like the only way to fight fire is with fire for getting a gpu, im a bit of a noob at coding but I came across one issue. so the bot i made searches for 2 elements "btn-disabled" (meaning its sold out) and "btn-primary" (meaning in stock) but here is my issue now. when the item I'm looking for is btn-disabled it finds btn-primary is ready at the bottom of the page aka BestBuy has a section if you scroll down a bit for other items you may be interested in. is their any fix to this???

Comment: Try a different tag to search the elements (e.g. if btn-primary + another)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific page you are parsing one can only guess at a solution, but you have for the most part answered your own question. The string `btn-disabled`is not unique enough on the page to trigger a positive match in your algorithm.

Some Suggestions:

- Look for other unique characteristics of "sold out" items, like the the string "Sold Out" for instance.
- See if you can create a version of the HTTP request with attributes that only return the subset of data which makes your algorithm work just fine. (i.e. no interested items, etc...)
- If you can't modify the HTTP request to minimize the data returned in the HTTP response, find a way to get your bot to ignore the data beyond one specific point in the page. Like at the tag that starts the "interested items" section.

*(Edit added after comments containing code and pages to be parsed.)*

Your code will have to make some assumptions about every page being parsed, but this may help:

```
buyButton = False
while not buyButton: 
try: browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-disabled") 
     print("Button isnt ready yet.")
     time.sleep(5) 
     browser.refresh(3) 
except: addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("add-to-cart-button") 
        print("Button was clicked") 
        addToCartBtn.click() 
        buyButton = True
```

I found through some source analysis that when an item is sold-out the Sold-Out button appears to include a `btn-disabled` class. So searching for that class FIRST may be a good way to immediately determine whether the item is sold-out. Now, if the class does NOT exist then the except gets triggered and you should then look for a button with the class `add-to-cart-button` which according to my analysis only exists on a button when the item is NOT sold-out. There are derivative strings that look like the `add-to-cart-button` but as far as I can tell the only one that is a class value appears to be the one on the main item's Add To Cart button.

Comment: Sorry for the late responce. https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3060-ti-8gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-graphics-card-steel-and-black/6439402.p?skuId=6439402 here is a example. Its on bestbuy.
buyButton = False

while not buyButton:

 try:

  addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("data-sku-id=6439402")

  print("Button isnt ready yet.")


  time.sleep(5)
  browser.refresh(3)

 except:

   addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary")

   print("Button was clicked")
   addToCartBtn.click()
   buyButton = True

Comment: Sorry for the spam in my last comment but that was the code i have so far. Im not sure what i should change it since its picking up the same element at the bottom of the screen as well. how would i go about making it specific with the sku for example?

Comment: You should not post your code in the comments. Include the code as part of your question above.